# Error when encoding array of object to UserDefaults in swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, nsuserdefaults

I have an array of Folder which store name and menuID like this

```
struct Folder {
    let name:String
    let menu:[String:Any]
}
```

Then I have the array of Folder which I will query from Firestore, then set to UserDefaults

```
var folders = [Folder]()

func getFolders() {
    self.userFolders.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
         print("Error getting Folders: \(err)")
      }
      else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
          let folder = Folder(name: document.documentID, menu: document.data())
           self.folders.append(folder)
        }
      }

      for f in self.folders {
         print(f)   // try to print out what is in self.folders
      }

      // try to encode the folders ** --- Error occurs in this line --- **
      let encodeFolders = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.folders)

      UserDefaults.standard.set(encodeFolders, forKey: "userFoldersArray")
   }
}
```

The contents inside self.folders are

```
Folder(name: "Default", menu: ["menuID": ])
Folder(name: "Test", menu: ["menuID": ])
Folder(name: "all", menu: ["menuID": menu1])
Folder(name: "favorite", menu: ["menuID": menu2])
```

The problem is in the encode line. This is what an error said :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001e9d80'
```

How can I fix this ? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: When using `NSKeyedArchiver`, you need to make your struct  (and all sub-ones too) conform to `NSCoding` protocol. Did you do so, I don't think so. What about using Codable to do so?

Comment: I don't think I have done that. I will have a look at Codable then. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

`NSCoding` requires the `NSObjectProtocol`. Only Classes can conform to this and you're using a Struct. ie:

```
struct Folder {
    let name:String
    let menu:[String:Any]
}
```

You can also read [this post](https://khanlou.com/2016/10/structs-and-nscoding/) in detail if you wish.